# Make helm-find-files work with `\input{file}` in latex files

Tags: helm, auctex, ffap

If the cursor is on `file` of a line `\input{file}` in a latex file, `helm-find-files` doesn't recognize that I want to open `file.tex`, however calling `ffap` does. If I write `\input{file.tex}` it also works with helm.

So how can I make helm to recognize this case (same with `\include`).

Comment: Related: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/4136